# Display markdown file from path in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown

I'm trying to create some routes to different .md files in my react/typescript app.

My App.tsx has this:

```
<Router>
  <main>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white sticky-top px-3">
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link active" href="/#About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link active" href="/FirstDoc">FirstDoc</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link active" href="/SecondDoc">SecondDoc</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
       <Route path="/FirstDoc" element={<FIFI />}></Route>
       <Route path="/SecondDoc" element={<SESE />}></Route>
     </Routes>

     <div className="row row-cols-sm-1 py-5 m-0 text-center">
       <hr className="my-4"/>
       <div className="col p-3">
         <p className="m-0">This is my footer</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </main>
 </Router>
```

I'm importing FirstDoc and SecondDoc from a file called MdFiles.tsx that looks like this:

```
import React, {FC} from "react"
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'

const fifiDoc = "./docs/FirstDoc.md"
const seseDoc = "./docs/SecondDoc.md"

const FIFI: FC = () => {
  return(
    <ReactMarkdown children={fifiDoc} />
  );
}

const SESE: FC = () => {
      
  return(
    <ReactMarkdown children={seseDoc} />
  );
}

export {FIFI, SESE};
```

I want my app to display de .md content inside the routes container but when it runs it shows the docs' paths as is

e.g.

Header with nav

> ./docs/FirstDoc.md

Footer

and

Header with nav

> ./docs/SecondDoc.md

Footer

because is taking them as a string.

I need it to get the text that is inside the paths related files and display it, I would love to write all the content when I'm creating `const fifiDoc` and `const seseDoc` but is very long and will be better to import it from the .md files.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
const [text, setText] = useState('')
useEffect(()=>{
const firstPath = require("./firstDoc.md");

  fetch(firstPath)
    .then(response => {
      return response.text()
    })
    .then(text => setText(text))
},[])
```

Then pass this text to the component with children prop.

```
<ReactMarkdown children={text} />
```

or

```
<ReactMarkdown>{text}</ReactMarkdown>
```

And check out these [article](https://pretagteam.com/question/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component). Play around with promises and file uploads to react.
I'm sure you will succeed.

Comment: (not OP) not sure why but I got a Proxy error when using your method for getting firstPath and didn't feel like figuring out why (my setup uses react & express), so I used `import firstPath from "./firstDoc.md");` and it worked.

Comment: Woked for me, just did some adjustments and in my case, I had to add `.default` when using `fetch`